# Find matrix of polynomial linear transformation relative to basis

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have been attempting quite a few of these "find the matrix from the linear transformation" problems and I have been stuck on this problem for some time.  For the standard bases what I have is

\begin{bmatrix}
    p(1)       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & p\prime(1) & 0 \\
    \\
    0       & 0 & p\prime\prime(-1) 
\end{bmatrix}

and here's what I have for the other basis

\begin{bmatrix}
    p(1)       & p(1) & p(1) \\
    0       & p\prime(1) & p\prime(1) \\
    \\
    0       & 0 & p\prime\prime(-1) 
\end{bmatrix}

Thanks in advance!

> Let $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ be the linear transformation given by 
>   $$T(p)=(p(1), p\prime(1), p\prime\prime(-1))$$.
>
> Find the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and the basis 
>   $$v_1=(1,0,0), v_2=(1,1,0), v_3=(1,1,1)$$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: Why do you tell us what the standard basis of $P_3(R)$ actually is, and for each vector $p$ in that basis, tell us what you computed as $T(p)$?That wy we'll know a bit more of what you actually know how to do. (You can edit your question by clicking on "edit" just below the question, to show your partial work.)

Comment: What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: What is $P_3(\mathbb{R})$? Is it the vector space (algebra actually) of the polynomials of degree less than $3$, at most $3$, or something else?
Telling us the "standard basis" would have clarified the question

Comment: Agree with john hughes on this that it would be more helpful if you show what you've done. Best

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: @Tancredi  It's with degree exactly 3

Comment: In this case it is not a vector space, think about it and reformulate

Comment: I get what you're saying I made a mistake in interpreting it as exactly 3.  It is likely at most 3 then.  Are the matrices I proposed in my edit correct in answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: would suggest by writing $p=ax^2+bx+c$ and seeing what happens to it by applying the transformation T.

(If the non-standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is confusing then perhaps do the problem with respect to the standard basis first).